# v8 - how to debug Map.prototype.set and OrderedHashTable?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm learning more about `v8` internals as a hobby project. For this example, I'm trying to debug and understand how Javascript `Map.prototype.set` actually works under-the-hood.

I'm using `v8` tag `9.9.99`.

I first create a new `Map` object in:

```
V8 version 9.9.99
d8> x = new Map()
[object Map]
d8> x.set(10,-10)
[object Map]
d8> %DebugPrint(x)
DebugPrint: 0x346c0804ad25: [JSMap]
 - map: 0x346c08202771 <Map(HOLEY_ELEMENTS)> [FastProperties]
 - prototype: 0x346c081c592d <Object map = 0x346c08202799>
 - elements: 0x346c08002249 <FixedArray[0]> [HOLEY_ELEMENTS]
 - table: 0x346c0804ad35 <OrderedHashMap[17]>
 - properties: 0x346c08002249 <FixedArray[0]>
 - All own properties (excluding elements): {}
```

When I break out of `d8` into `gdb`, I look into the `table` attribute

```
gef➤  job 0x346c0804ad35
0x346c0804ad35: [OrderedHashMap]
 - FixedArray length: 17
 - elements: 1
 - deleted: 0
 - buckets: 2
 - capacity: 4
 - buckets: {
          0: -1
          1: 0
 }
 - elements: {
          0: 10 -> -10
 }
```

Poking around the `v8` source, I find what I think to be the code related to `OrderedHashTable` and `OrderedHashMap` in `src/objects/ordered-hash-table.cc`. Specifically, line 368:

```
MaybeHandle<OrderedHashMap> OrderedHashMap::Add(Isolate* isolate,
                                            Handle<OrderedHashMap> table,
                                            Handle<Object> key,
                                            Handle<Object> value) {
...
```

After reading the code, my assumption is that `OrderedHashMap::Add()` will get triggered when you do `Map.Prototype.Set` (i.e., adding a new element). So I set a breakpoint here in and continue

```
gef➤  b v8::internal::OrderedHashMap::Add(v8::internal::Isolate*, 
v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap>, 
v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>)
Breakpoint 1 at 0x557eb3b491e4
gef➤  c
Continuing.
```

I then attempt to set a new element, but the breakpoint does **not** trigger

```
d8> x.set(11,-11)
[object Map]
```

Breaking out into `gdb` again, it appears the element has been added

```
gef➤  job 0x346c0804ad35
0x346c0804ad35: [OrderedHashMap]
 - FixedArray length: 17
 - elements: 2
 - deleted: 0
 - buckets: 2
 - capacity: 4
 - buckets: {
              0: 1
              1: 0
 }
 - elements: {
              0: 10 -> -10
              1: 11 -> -11
 }
```

Do I have the breakpoint set up in the wrong spot? And if so, would anyone have any recommendations for efficiently finding the JS equivalents in `v8`?

Comment: I think you mean `Map.prototype.set`. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: This is actually a `c++` question even though it relates to the implementation of a javascript method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

Many things in V8 have more than one implementation, for various reasons: in this case, there's the C++ way of adding an entry to an `OrderedHashMap` (which you've found), and there's also a generated-code way of doing it. If you grep for `MapPrototypeSet`, you'll find `TF_BUILTIN(MapPrototypeSet, ...` in [builtins-collections-gen.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/src/builtins/builtins-collections-gen.cc#1634), which is the canonical implementation of `Map.prototype.set`. Since that's a piece of code that runs at V8 build time to generate a "stub" which is then embedded into the binary, there's no direct way of setting a breakpoint into that stub. One way to do it is to insert a `DebugBreak()` call into the stub-generating code, and recompile.

Not all builtins are implemented in the same way:

- some (like M.p.set) are generated "[CSA builtins](https://v8.dev/docs/csa-builtins)" in `src/builtins/*-gen.cc`
- some are regular C++ in `src/builtins/*.cc`
- some are written in [Torque](https://v8.dev/docs/torque-builtins) (`src/builtins/*.tq`) which is V8's own DSL that translates to CSA
- some have fast paths directly in the compiler(s)
- some have their meat in "runtime functions" (`src/runtime/*.cc`)

Many have more than one implementation (typically a fully spec-compliant "slow" fallback, often but not always in C++, and then one or more fast paths that take shortcuts for common situations, often but not always in various forms of generated code). There are probably also a few special cases I'm forgetting right now; and as this post ages over the years, the enumeration above will become outdated (e.g. there used to be builtins in handwritten assembly, but we got rid of (almost all) of them; there used to be builtins generated by the old Crankshaft compiler, but we replaced that; there used to be builtins written in JavaScript, but we got rid of them; CSA was new at some point; Torque was new at some point; who knows what'll come next).

One consequence of all this is that questions like "how exactly does JavaScript's feature X work under the hood?" often don't have a concise answer.

Have fun with your investigation!

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response! That clears things up a lot :)